# Enforcing files in a folder have build action = Embedded Resource with target files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, target

The Visual Studio project has a folder containing sql scripts and all files in it must have the build action set to Embedded Resource. While adding new files, developers often forget to change the build action.

I want to create a target file that throws an error a compile time if any of the files in the folder do not have the correct build action.

I have seen something similar done before.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" 
         DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="MakeSureSqlFilesAreSetToCopyAlways" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Error Condition="!('%(Content.CopyToOutputDirectory)' == 'Always')" 
           Text="This Content file is not configured to Copy Always: [%(Content.FullPath)]" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This block of code checks if the files are set to copy always. How do I check build action?

Would appreciate some links to further reading on this topic as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that script files are in a folder called `Scripts`, the following target file will raise an error if there's any file with build action set to `Content` and if their path contains the word `Scripts`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" 
         DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="MakeSureSqlFilesAreSetToEmbeddedAsResource" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Error Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(Content.FullPath)', 'Scripts'))" 
           Text="This Content file is not configured as Embedded Resource: [%(Content.FullPath)]" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If you're dealing with developers who forget to set their scripts as Embedded Resource, the above should be enough (though not comprehensive), mainly because Visual Studio sets the build action for new files to `Content` by default. If you want to make it bullet proof simply repeat the `Error` tag and replace `Content` with all possible build actions (except `EmbeddedResource`).